# 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'save' Error Occurred

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am a student studying Django. Currently, the member information has been entered in the Member table. I want to create Mypage so that member information registered in the Member table can be modified, and develop so that member information can be modified on Mypage. But while developing, I faced the following error: How can I solve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

***Detail Error :***

```
AttributeError at /mypage/mypage_modify/
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'save'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/mypage/mypage_modify/
Django Version: 3.1.5
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'save'
Exception Location: C:\zeronine_project\mypage\views.py, line 27, in mypage_modify
Python Executable:  D:\anaconda3\envs\vnv_zn\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.6
Python Path:    
['C:\\zeronine_project',
 'D:\\anaconda3\\envs\\vnv_zn\\python37.zip',
 'D:\\anaconda3\\envs\\vnv_zn\\DLLs',
 'D:\\anaconda3\\envs\\vnv_zn\\lib',
 'D:\\anaconda3\\envs\\vnv_zn',
 'D:\\anaconda3\\envs\\vnv_zn\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 08 Jul 2021 21:05:53 +0900
```

**view.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

from mypage.forms import *
from zeronine.models import *

# Create your views here.

def mypage_list(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'mypage/mypage_list.html', {'categories':categories})


def mypage_modify(request):
    current_category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    member = Member.objects.all()

    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('zeronine:login'))

    if request.method == "POST":
        member.name = request.POST['name']
        member.password = request.POST['password']
        member.username = request.user
        member.save()
        return redirect('zeronine:post')

    else:
        memberForm = MemberForm
        return render(request, 'mypage/mypage_modify.html', {'memberForm':memberForm, 'member':member, 'current_category': current_category, 'categories': categories})
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.urls import reverse

# 회원
class Member(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=20, verbose_name='아이디')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='이름', default='')
    password = models.CharField(max_length=64, verbose_name='비밀번호')
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=64, verbose_name='전화번호')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ('Member')
        verbose_name_plural = ('Members')

# 카테고리
class Category(models.Model):
    category_code = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True, allow_unicode=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering =['category_code']
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('zeronine:product_in_category', args=[self.slug])

# 상품
class Product(models.Model):
    product_code = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.ForeignKey(Member, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='username')
    category_code = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='products')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True, unique=False, allow_unicode=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
    benefit = models.TextField()
    detail = models.TextField()
    target_price = models.IntegerField()
    start_date = models.DateField()
    due_date = models.DateField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['product_code']
        index_together = [['product_code', 'slug']]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('zeronine:product_detail', args=[self.product_code, self.slug])


class Post(models.Model):
    post_code = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.ForeignKey(Member, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='username')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    content = models.TextField()
    register_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['register_date']

# 댓글(댓글코드, 게시글코드(fk), 아이디(fk), 내용, 등록날짜)
class Comment(models.Model):
    comment_code = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    post_code = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='post_code')
    username = models.ForeignKey(Member, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='username')
    content = models.TextField()
    register_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['register_date']

# Zzim 모델부터 새로 추가하려는 모델들 입니다.

# 찜하기(찜코드, 아이디(fk), 상품코드(fk))
class Zzim(models.Model):
    zzim_code = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.ForeignKey(Member, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='username')
    product_code = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='product_code')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.zzim_code)

# 상품이미지(이미지코드, 상품코드(fk), 이미지경로)
class Photo(models.Model):
    photo_code = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    product_code = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='product_code')
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos/%Y%m%d")

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.photo_code)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['photo_code']


# 옵션(옵션코드, 옵션명, 상품코드(fk))
class Option(models.Model):
    option_code = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    product_code = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='product_code')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

# 옵션값(옵션값코드, 옵션값명, 옵션코드(fk), 상품코드(fk))
class Value(models.Model):
    value_code = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    option_code = models.ForeignKey(Option, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='option_code')
    product_code = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='product_code')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

# 옵션지정상품(옵션지정상품코드, 상품코드(fk), 가격, 참여수량)
class Designated(models.Model):
    designated_code = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    product_code = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='product_code')
    price = models.IntegerField()
    rep_price = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['designated_code']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.designated_code)

# 상품옵션구성(상품옵션구성코드, 옵션지정상품코드, 옵션값코드)
class Element(models.Model):
    element_code = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    designated_code = models.ForeignKey(Designated, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='designated_code')
    value_code = models.ForeignKey(Value, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='value_code')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['element_code']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.element_code)

# 참여(참여코드, 아이디(fk), 상품코드(fk), 수량)
class Join(models.Model):
    join_code = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.ForeignKey(Member, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='username')
    product_code = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='product_code')
    part_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.join_code)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['join_code']

#참여상세(참여상세코드, 수량, 가격, 참여코드, 옵션지정상품코드)
class JoinDetail(models.Model):
    joindetail_code = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    join_code = models.ForeignKey(Join, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='join_code')
    designated_code = models.ForeignKey(Designated, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, db_column='designated_code')
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.joindetail_code)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['joindetail_code']
```

Comment: The problem is caused by this line: `member = Member.objects.all()`. member now has all of the instances of Member model, but you are using it as if it is just one instance. Did you forget to get the exact member you want to modify?

Comment: @bdbd I think it's confusing because I use Django's default user model and the Member table I created together. Autofield does not exist in Member table, so it cannot be developed using id or pk value. How should I fix it? I tried to modify it using filter or get, but it doesn't work. I want to develop so that all members registered in the model can use My Page to edit their member information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not specifying a `member` object to update. `member = Member.objects.all()` will get a queryset of all the `member` objects in your database.

Try doing:

```
def mypage_modify(request):
   current_category = None
   categories = Category.objects.all()
   member = Member.objects.all()

   if not request.user.is_authenticated:
       return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('zeronine:login'))

   if request.method == "POST":
       member = Member.objects.get(name=request.POST['name']) #specifying the member
       member.name = request.POST['name']
       member.password = request.POST['password']
       member.username = request.user
       member.save()
       return redirect('zeronine:post')

   else:
       memberForm = MemberForm
       return render(request, 'mypage/mypage_modify.html', {'memberForm':memberForm, 'member':member, 'current_category': current_category, 'categories': categories})
```

Or if you are making a new member object then instead of `member = Member.objects.get(name=request.POST['name'])`

Do: `member = Member()`

EDIT:

Not sure why you'd want to do this in practise, but to change every member object in the database you'd do the following:

```
def mypage_modify(request):
   current_category = None
   categories = Category.objects.all()
   member = Member.objects.all()

   if not request.user.is_authenticated:
       return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('zeronine:login'))
   if request.method == "POST":
       for m in member:
          m.name = request.POST['name']
          m.password = request.POST['password']
          m.username = request.user
          m.save()
       return redirect('zeronine:post')
```

Comment: Thanks for posting a reply. However, I would like to be able to freely modify all of the names, IDs, emails, and passwords registered in the member table. In this case, how do I call it?

Comment: Thank you. Your answer was helpful. But if I can distribute it wrong, the name and password are all terrible, only the user name is not modified. The problem?

Comment: @roboca usernames have to be unique, you cannot have multiple entries in your database with the same username.

Comment: It really helped a lot. Thank you. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

What you're accessing with `member = Member.objects.all()` is a list of `Member` objects.
To get a desired member use

```
member = Member.objects.get()
```

or

```
member = Member.objects.filter()
```

In the latter, you'd also need to check

```
if member:
    member = member.first()
```

Check
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#filter
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#get

Comment: Thanks for posting a reply. However, I would like to be able to freely modify all of the names, IDs, emails, and passwords registered in the member table. In this case, how do I call it?